# How do I allow all renderers to have access to the preload's functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to have my main renderer open up a second renderer, which will display a file (like an image or a video). I have a function that can do this in `renderer.js`, and it works perfectly, but when I try to use it in `specific.js`, it throws a `Cannot read property of undefined, 'openFile()'`.

```
//main.js
const { app, BroswerWindow, ipcMain, dialog } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

async function handleFileOpen() {
    const {canceled, filePath} = await dialog.showOpenDialog()
    if(canceled) return

    let fullPath = path.resolve(filePaths[0])
    let name = path.basename(fullPath)
    let extension = path.extname(name)

    return {
        filePath: fullPath.
        name: name,
        extension: extension
    }
}

const createWindow = () => {
    //created the window with preload.js as the preload under webPreferences
}

app.whenRead().then(() => {
    ipcMain.handle('dialog:openFile', handleFileOpen)
    //other ipc communications not used in this example

    createWindow()
})
```

```
//preload.js
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    openFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile')
    //other ipc references similar to the one above
})
```

`specific.js` is in the same folder as `main.js`,`preload.js` and `renderer.js`. It is also in the same folder as the html file that references it with a script tag. It should also be noted that the code for the `openFile()` function is a modified version of an example given by electron's documentation: [ipc pattern#2 renderer-to-main two-way](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way). I'm also aware of the `contextBridge.exposeInIsolatedWorld()` function, but I can't find anything in the documentation on how I would get the `worldId`.

How do I allow `specific.js` to use `openFile()`?

Comment: You don't need to "allow" any renderer to use specific preload functions but you sadly didn't include the code that actually constructs your second window. Thus, we can only make assumptions – please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. Since you also didn't show us the code of `specific.js`, we don't know how you tried to call `openFile` and can thus not investigate where the error is coming from. *Please* [edit] your question to fill in the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a second function in `main.js` that makes a new window with access to `preload.js` through the `webPreferences: {preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'}`